# How do I force a compile on code that has errors?

Tags: typescript

The current API I am using hooks into C++ code, which has it's own includes. I want to reference these libraries (through the C++ code) inside of the TS code I am writing (which the C++ reads and behaves accordingly). It shows errors in VS, which is fine, as I know what the errors are, and that it won't cause any trouble down the line. I have copied the code into the Play section on TS website, and used that JS with no problems. I want to know how to compile the TS code into JS code using VS, ignoring errors (bonus points for selective ignorance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already the behavior. The TypeScript compiler will emit JS unless you have parse errors (i.e. syntax problems).

Comment: Hmm. I'm having a problem compiling then, I guess. I have a solution with zero projects, as I just wish to create single TS files. When I save, there are no .js files generated. Also, when I drag+drop on to the tsc.exe, nothing is created in either the tsc.exe containing folder, or the source folder of the TS. Any guesses?